# How to Show tooltip on multiselect box with jsp?

Tags: jquery, jsp, tooltip, jquery-hover

```
<div class="span3">
                <label>Restaurants <span class="f_req">*</span></label> <select
                    id="rest_id" name="rest_id"
                    data-placeholder="- Select Restaurants -" class="chzn-select"multiple ">
                    <%
                        List <restaurant> rest_list=restaurantLocalServiceUtil.getAllRestaurantByOrganizationId(themeDisplay);                                                          
                                                        for(int i=0;i<rest_list.size();i++) {
                    %>
                    <option id="<%=rest_list.get(i).getPrimaryKey()%>"
                        value=<%=rest_list.get(i).getPrimaryKey()%>><%=rest_list.get(i).getName().toString()%>
                    </option>
                    <%
                        }
                    %>
                </select> <span id="restError3" style="color: #C62626;" class="help-block"></span>
            </div>
```

Above is the snippet of my one division in jsp code.which list the restaurants in multiselect box.
what i want to do is that i want to show some other details about the restaurant as a tooltip on mouseover on the restaurant name which are in the list box or on selcted restaurant...tooltip details like (restaurant City,or Adress,or State)
..so how can i show that?can anyone tell me how to do it?

Answer (score 2):

The tooltip is represented by the HTML element's `title` attribute.

For example,

```
<option value="42" title="This is option with label 'Foo' and ID 42">Foo</option>
```

---

I'm not sure why you tagged this jQuery, but if you want fanciness, then just pick one of the many available [jQuery tooltip plugins](http://google.com/search?q=jquery%20tooltip%20plugin). Do however note that almost all of them do that based on the value of the HTML element's `title` attribute. The only what they effectively do is to turn the "standard" tooltip look'n'feel into some flashy look'n'feel by removing the `title` attribute and baking a bunch of `<div>` and CSS, etc boilerblate which shows up on mouse over.